# Moved from CA to WA, will CA refund me all the withheld payroll taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax, california

Moved to WA on Mar-end, and my last paycheck from CA was received on mid-Mar.
As a result, I've received 2 x W2s. One for CA income, and the other for WA income.

As far as I understand, given I spent less than 9 months (3 in my case) in CA, I should be considered a tax resident of WA.

Will CA refund me all of the with-held taxes during 2023?
Will I need to file a CA tax return and a WA tax return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be considered a [part-year resident of California](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/personal/residency-status/part-year-and-nonresident.html) and will need to file [CA Form 540NR](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2023/2023-540nr.pdf) to determine if any of the CA state withholding will be refunded, or if you owe more. CA tax is determined by `tax on total income x (CA income / total income)` rather than `tax on CA income`, so the tax will not be artificially low due to only working 3 months there. The good news is Washington state has no state income tax so there is no return you'd need to file there, unless you had significant [long-term capital gains](https://dor.wa.gov/taxes-rates/other-taxes/capital-gains-tax).

Comment: Given CA income is expected to be roughly 3/12 ~ 1/4th of total annual income, will CA tax rate be lower given the lower CA income or will it decide the tax rate based on annual income?

Comment: @YugalJindle CA tax rate will be determined based on total income, then CA tax (but not tax rate) will be scaled based on CA income / total income.